# Node module doesn't work after webpack build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, node-modules

I'm having some problems with building own node module for my react  apps. I need this to prepare some common functions for couple of my react apps and I want them to be placed in separated node module. So, I created the module and it looks like that:

`-src
--index.js
-package.json`

index.js file:

```
export const myFunction = () => {
  return 'Some nice text';
}
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "mymodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "src/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "npm test"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
}
```

In the react app (consumer project) I'm importing the function:

```
import { myFunction } from 'mymodule';

console.log(myFunction());
```

Till now, everything works fine. In the console I see the text `Some nice text`.
Now, I'm trying to build my module with webpack 4 so I updated my `package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "mymodule",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/main.js", <-- this is the file build by webpack
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^4.21.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
  }
}
```

and rebuild both projects. Then I see in the console following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _mymodule.myFunction) is not a function
    at eval (index.jsx:47)
    at Object../src/index.jsx (main.js:8559)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_(:8080/webpack)-dev-server/client?:3:18)
    at Object.0 (main.js:9057)
    at __webpack_require__ (main.js:20)
    at main.js:84
    at main.js:87
```

EDIT:
I added babel as suggested and turned off minimization. This is how my `dist/main.js` file looks like:

```
/******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, { enumerable: true, get: getter });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // define __esModule on exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.r = function(exports) {
/******/        if(typeof Symbol !== 'undefined' && Symbol.toStringTag) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, Symbol.toStringTag, { value: 'Module' });
/******/        }
/******/        Object.defineProperty(exports, '__esModule', { value: true });
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // create a fake namespace object
/******/    // mode & 1: value is a module id, require it
/******/    // mode & 2: merge all properties of value into the ns
/******/    // mode & 4: return value when already ns object
/******/    // mode & 8|1: behave like require
/******/    __webpack_require__.t = function(value, mode) {
/******/        if(mode & 1) value = __webpack_require__(value);
/******/        if(mode & 8) return value;
/******/        if((mode & 4) && typeof value === 'object' && value && value.__esModule) return value;
/******/        var ns = Object.create(null);
/******/        __webpack_require__.r(ns);
/******/        Object.defineProperty(ns, 'default', { enumerable: true, value: value });
/******/        if(mode & 2 && typeof value != 'string') for(var key in value) __webpack_require__.d(ns, key, function(key) { return value[key]; }.bind(null, key));
/******/        return ns;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
__webpack_require__.r(__webpack_exports__);
/* harmony export (binding) */ __webpack_require__.d(__webpack_exports__, "myFunction", function() { return myFunction; });
function myFunction() {
  return 'aaaaaabbbb';
}
```

Has somebody faced similar issue? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to upgrade babel versions as well.  If you change myFunction to regular function instead of arrow function it would work.

Comment: @Think-Twice, added the newest babel version and still doesn't work. Also, changed from arrow function to normal function and it didn't help. Updated the question to show not minimized build file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with build config. This build file doesn't export the function outside. To do it, let's add `output` key to webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    ...
    output: {
        library: 'modulename',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    ...
};
```

Then, the module functions will be exported outside.